# Less saturated fat in curry

Tags: fat, curry

By "curry" I mean the meal I make at home: start by frying some Mae Ploy curry paste, stir in coconut milk, toss in a bit of sugar, add vegetables, and simmer until everything is just right.

I was recently diagnosed with high cholesterol and my doctor told me to lay off the saturated fats.

I've tried using substitutes like soy milk and oat milk along with a bit of coconut extract and the flavor seems pretty good to me, but the curry doesn't have the same mouthfeel as it does with coconut milk.

Here's the question: are there non-saturated fats (or other ingredients) I could add to give the curry a thicker mouthfeel without affecting the flavor?

Comment: Not an answer, but you could always try swapping to Jungle Curry… similar thing to green, but no coconut milk at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's a great idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well.. No. the problem is, that mouthfeel *is* the mouthfeel of saturated fat. You could substitute with palm kernel oil, with margarine, with suet… all because of their saturated fat content.

A bit of gelatin may help; so may a **TINY** bit of xanthan gum; so may cornstarch or tapioca starch slurry mixed in and simmered for a couple of minutes. But as you can see from the utter lack of healthy butter substitutes, you can’t fool your tongue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: One thing to bare in mind with Xanthan gum is that as soon as you add it to a liquid, it will gel and you can find yourself with little white pearls of Xanthan gum that has gelled on the outside but that will remain powdery on the inside. They're not nice to eat and they can be difficult to get rid of, especially in something you can't process in a blender or with an immersion blender. So just remember that you should add it sparingly, gradually, and whilst stirring vigorously.... and again, a little goes a long way.